# Is there a set of natural numbers such that iterating the construction as in Euclid's proof generates only ever more prime numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

In [Euclid's proof of the infinitude of prime numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_theorem#Euclid%27s_proof), from a given set $\mathcal P$ of prime numbers the number $1 + \prod\limits_{p \, \in \, \mathcal P} \! p$ is constructed (followed by the argument that this constructed number cannot be devided by any number $p \in \mathcal P$).

Starting out with any non-empty (but finite) set $\mathcal S_1$ of natural numbers, the described construction can be applied iteratively, whereby

$\mathcal S_{(n + 1)} := \text{Union}[ \, \mathcal S_n, \{ 1 + \prod\limits_{s \, \in \, \mathcal S_n} \! \! s \} \, ],$

and where, obviously, the newly constructed number $1 + \prod\limits_{s \, \in \, \mathcal S_n} \! \! s $ is larger than any number $s \in \mathcal S_n$.

**My question:**

Does there exist a set $\mathcal S_1^{\ast}$ of natural numbers such that, by iterating the described construction, **all** successively constructed numbers
$ 1 + \prod\limits_{s \, \in \, \mathcal S^{\ast}_n} \! \! s $ are **prime numbers** ?

Comment: Isn't this equivalent to the case where we just start with one number?

Comment: @Yorch: "_Isn't this equivalent to the case where we just start with one number?_" -- Yes, indeed, my OP problem about a suitable set $\mathcal S_1^{\ast}$ is equivalent to starting out with a set with only one element of value $\prod\limits_{s \, \in \, \mathcal S^{\ast}_1} \! \! s $. Thanks for pointing this out! But: Is there any further consequence to finding an answer to my problem ?? ...

Comment: @Yorch: Well, certainly set $\mathcal S^{\ast}_1$ must contain at least one even number. In consequence, starting with only one suitable number, it must be even.

Comment: Constructing infinite sequences of prime integers by arithmetic operations is exceedingly difficult.

Comment: @Somos: "_Constructing infinite sequences of prime integers by arithmetic operations is exceedingly difficult._" -- I sure hope so. (If "they" hadn't (effectively) kicked me out of _MathOverflow_ I might have asked my question there. ... &)

Comment: I don't know if this reformulation is useful, but the problem is equivalent to asking whethere there is a positive integer $n$ such that $n,p(n),p^2(n),\dots$ are all prime, where $p(x) = x^2-x+1$.

Comment: @Yorch I don't know whether this is helpful, but based on your reformulation $p(x)=x^2-x+1$, we can see that if the starting prime ends in the digit $1$, then all progeny end in the digit $1$. $5$ yields no progeny. Any other starting prime quickly produces progeny whose last digits oscillate between $3$ and $7$.

Comment: @Yorch: "_[...] the problem is equivalent to asking [...]_" -- Yes, I agree that your reformulation is equivalent to the OP problem; I just prefer a different style of formatting: The OP problem is equivalent to asking whether there is a prime number $p > 1$ such that all of $f[ \, p \, ], (f^2)[ \, p \, ], \dots, (f^n)[ \, p \, ], \dots$ are prime numbers as well, where $f[ \, x \, ] \mapsto x^2 - x + 1$. This is equivalent to the OP problem by setting $\mathcal S_0 := \{ (p - 1) \}$ (or to some set of factors which make up the product value $p - 1$).